# How to format an output?

Tags: java, formatting

(In Java) Write a program that accepts names and formats them as follows: If the input is:
John Anthony Brown

Then the output must be:
Brown, John A.

Here is what I have

```
    int mn;
    String input3;
    int fn;
    int ln;
    String firstName;
    String lastName;
    String middleName;
    Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
    String input = scnr.nextLine();
    fn = input.indexOf(" ");
    firstName = input.substring(0, fn);
    middleName = input.substring(fn+1, input.length());
    mn = middleName.indexOf(" ");
    lastName = input.substring(mn+1, input.length());
    
    System.out.println(lastName + ", " + mn + " " + firstName + ".");
}
```

I keep trying different things and get weird outputs such as "ry A Lee, 1 Mary." for the input "Marry A Lee"

This topic was never covered in my class and I am very confused.

Comment: You can split a String `str` by whitespaces with `String[] splited = str.split("\\s+");`. In your example, `splited` will be `{"John", "Anthony", "Brown"}`. Hope this tip helps :)

Comment: `mn = fn + 1 + middleName.indexOf(" ");` might help, since you want an index into `input`, based on a string already chopped out of input.

Answer (score 0):

Because this is homework, I’ll give code fragments:

Firstly, use `split()` to break up the text into words:

```
String[] names = input.split(" ");
```

Then build up your result:

```
String result = names[2] + ", " + names[0] + ", " + names[1].charAt(0) + ".";
```

There are more elegant ways of doing it, but this way is arguably the easiest to understand.

You could get fancier by catering for varying numbers of names.

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this:

```
String[] items = input.split(" ");

//if there are three item in items, then it is the pattern you mentioned
if (items.length == 3) {
    System.out.println(items[2] + "," + items[0] + items[1].charAt(0) + ".");
}
```